# Why doesn't std::generate compile in this example?

Tags: c++

```
#include "Functions.hpp"
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using std::numeric_limits;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;


std::deque<bool> retBernoulli(double p, int seed, int size)
{
    
    std::bernoulli_distribution dist(p);
    std::mt19937_64 mtre(seed);
    std::deque<bool> bernies(size);
    
    auto oneBernoulli = [](std::mt19937_64 mtre, std::bernoulli_distribution dist)
    {
        return dist(mtre);
    };
    
    //Check if inputs are valid
    if (p < 0 || p > 1 || seed < 0 || size < 0)
    {
        cout << "Oops....not a number. Check your inputs" << endl;
        return numeric_limits<std::deque<bool>>::quiet_NaN();
    }
    
    else
    {
        std::generate(bernies.begin(), bernies.end(), oneBernoulli(mtre, dist));
        
        //print contents of bernies
        //print(bernies);
        return bernies;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to generate an STL container with random variates of a Bernoulli Distribution using a lambda function as the generator function. I've initialized both the Bernoulli distribution and the `mt19937_64` mersene twister engine. When compiling, it throws an exception back to the generate.h header file, specifically it highlights the generator function in the header as the problem. I'm sure there's something wrong with the syntax in my lambda function since I've been able to successfully use `std::generate` in other scripts.

Comment: If it doesn't compile, then include in your question the specific error message it generates.

Comment: I'd also suggest actually looking at the parameters generate is supposed to be have.... https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate

Comment: Regarding `numeric_limits<std::deque<bool>>::quiet_NaN()` It seems unlikely a non-numeric type like has a NaN representation. NaN is a special value floating point types may hold to indicate an arithmetic error. It isn't a general purpose null value, and it certainly can't be applied to a container.

Comment: olyjazzhead Have you had any chance at looking at the answer? If there's anything you'd like me to clarify, please just comment under the answer.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thank you for pointing this out. Although it produces a runtime error, interestingly enough it compiles.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you *call* the generator `oneBernoulli` instead of passing it to `std::generate` by value. The generator you pass to `generate` shouldn't take any arguments.

From [`std::generate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate):

> The signature of the function should be equivalent to the following:
>
> ```
> Ret fun();
> ```

Make it:

```cpp
auto oneBernoulli = [&mtre, &dist] { // doesn't take any arguments
    return dist(mtre);
};
```

and then

```cpp
std::generate(bernies.begin(), bernies.end(), oneBernoulli);
//                                                ^
//                                     pass generator by value
```

Comment: Hi Ted....thank you for your answer.....I just saw this so I apologize for the wait. I made your edits and it indeed did work. I will need to study it further to understand it better but in the meantime I appreciate your input!